# be able to detect shifts in C# forms

Tags: c#, forms

Ok I am writing a program in C# forms  to be able to look at the current date and determine what shift is currently on.  This would be easy if the shifts were the same each day, but this company uses a 2 on 2 off 3 on 3 off type rotation.  so shifts would be like the following

day 1, shifts A,B
day 2, Shifts A,B
day 3, shifts C,D

and so on.  I have to be able to detect the time (which I can do0 and determine by the date what shift should be working.  The customer wants it to roll over and be automated so the operators wont have to touch the system.

I have thought about using calendars, but cant seem to find one that is light weight enough to just do triggers, but easy to populate a long period of shift data.

thought about using an array and hard coding in the sequence of the shifts, but if the system is shut off for a day I need to be able to maintain the sequence.

I am not looking for programs or source code to do this,,, just mainly ideas and how I can organize the data.  Maybe I am just trying to make an easy task to hard

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to say "work shifts" since the title would imply you are looking for keyboard input help.  It's a little hard to answer your question without knowing a lot more about the requirements, but it seems like you could just make each shift an instance of a simple class that uses DateTime, TimeSpan, math, and some initial constructor value specific to that instance to figure out whether it's on or off.

Answer (score 0):

> thought about using an array and hard coding in the sequence of the shifts, but if the system is shut off for a day I need to be able to maintain the sequence.

This will work if you have a known start date in the past for each shift. If the shift always eventually repeats, you can determine where in the shift cycle you are based on that date:

Describe the shift schedule as a boolean array (e.g. 2 on 2 off, 3 on 3 off )

```
var shiftSchedule = new[] { true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false};
```

Take a known start date for that shift:

```
var shiftStartDate = DateTime.Today;
```

For any date after the known start date, determine the number of days between the known start date and the future date:

```
var shiftCheckDate = <somefuturedate>;
var diff = (shiftCheckDate - shiftStartDate).Days;
```

You can then take the number of days in the shift cycle, modulus the difference in days, as the shift array index to determine where you are in the shift cycle:

```
var shiftIsOn = shiftSchedule[(diff % shiftSchedule.Length)];
```

For example, if the shift rotation starts today (10/13/2017):

```
var shiftSchedule = new[] { true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false};
var shiftStartDate = DateTime.Today;
var shiftCheckDate = DateTime.Today;

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    var diff = (shiftCheckDate - shiftStartDate).Days;
    var shiftIsOn = shiftSchedule[(diff % shiftSchedule.Length)];
    Console.WriteLine($"{shiftCheckDate.ToShortDateString()} - {shiftIsOnToday}");
    shiftCheckDate = shiftCheckDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

returns

```
10/13/2017 - True
10/14/2017 - True
10/15/2017 - False
10/16/2017 - False
10/17/2017 - True
10/18/2017 - True
10/19/2017 - True
10/20/2017 - False
10/21/2017 - False
10/22/2017 - False
10/23/2017 - True
10/24/2017 - True
10/25/2017 - False
10/26/2017 - False
10/27/2017 - True
10/28/2017 - True
```

Definitely a quick and dirty solution, but hope it helps. Know you weren't looking for code but it was the easiest way to show an example. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a problem that is in the same ballpark with yours.  My answer:

I defined a schedule block.  This could be edited.  This was stored, as well as a list of exceptions to the pattern.  At runtime the calendar was recreated by tiling the pattern onto it and then applying the exceptions.  Note that this means that if the tiling were edited the historical calendar would be corrupted--in my case that was of no concern as this is purely about scheduling.  If you must maintain history then as days actually happen log them and use that instead.

I did not have to cope with the possibility of slippage but that would simply be a different sort of exception--here's a new start date for the tiling.